# Chrome Extensions public API or links to ask new versions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there any Chrome Extensions public API or links to ask new versions?
Any methods to send a request to extension API without credentials?
Or maybe some way to ask updates without javacript libs?

I am newby in Chrome Extensions.  I tried to find the way to do it outside the Extension, but still without luck.  I am expecting to call this link or API from Java based service.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "Chrome Extensions public API" so I guess you're looking for the [webstore API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/api_index/), but it doesn't have such features.

Comment: @wOxxOm, maybe I called something wrong.. I just want to know can I do it?

Comment: Assuming my guess about your objective is correct, there's no such API.